# How to trace any change in JTextField in order to update other textfields immediately?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I want to write a simple Swing application. It should do calculating a date based on user input (initial date and amount of days).
This's how my application is looking now.
[image]

However due to not big experience I encountered some problems with the application.

1. When a value in the middle field `textField` is changed there are no changes in `resultDayField` but only after pressing "Enter". I saw here different solutions how to trace changes with `DocumentListener` and `JFormattedField` but my case requires universal listener for all widgets in panel to trace changes simultaneously. I don't undestand how to mix `ActionListener` and `DocumentListener` to work them both. What should I do?
2. Also if the middle field `textField` is empty choosing any date will crash the application with null-pointer exception. But I didn't understand why the app can't just write "Null".
3. A strange piece of code

   ```
   SomeActionListener listen = new SomeActionListener(datePicker, textField, resultDateField);
   datePicker.addActionListener(listen);
   textField.addActionListener(listen);
   ```

   I'm not sure if it is good to do in that way.

Could you kindly comment these questions?

Here are two source files of the app.
First (main) is `TestJDatePicker.java`:

```
import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestJDatePicker extends JPanel {
    JTextField textField;
    JTextField resultDateField;
    JDatePicker datePicker;

    public TestJDatePicker() {

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("text.today", "Today");
        p.put("text.month", "Month");
        p.put("text.year", "Year");

        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setText("10");

        resultDateField = new JTextField(20);

        SomeActionListener listen = new SomeActionListener(datePicker, textField, resultDateField);

        datePicker.addActionListener(listen);
        textField.addActionListener(listen);

        add(datePicker);
        add(textField);
        add(resultDateField);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 450));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DocumentEventDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new TestJDatePicker();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second file which I wrote is `SomeActionListener.java`:

```
import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SomeActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField resultDateField;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JDatePickerImpl datePicker;
    //...

    public SomeActionListener(JDatePickerImpl datePicker, JTextField textField, JTextField resultDateField){
        this.textField=textField;
        this.datePicker=datePicker;
        this.resultDateField = resultDateField;
        //...
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
        //System.out.println(selectedDate);
        System.out.println(textField.getText());

        int days = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(selectedDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);

        resultDateField.setText(cal != null ? sdf.format(cal.getTime()) : null);
    }

}
```

Comment: *"but my case requires universal listener for all widgets in panel to trace changes simultaneously"* Does this mean that any change to any field could produce a change in the other fields?  If so, what's the relationship?

Comment: `int days = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());` will cause an `Exception` when the text field is empty, because `""` is not a valid number, you need to check if the field has a value first before you do any additional calculations.

Comment: A `DocumentListener` on the middle field is the best choice for detecting real time changes.  You could also consider a `JSpinner`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Left and middle fields should trace each other in order to calculate proper date in right field. Right field shouldn't be editable.

Comment: So, as I understand it, the left and middle fields, when changed, update the right field, but neither the left or right fields effect each other, right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, you're right. Sorry for disambiguation

Answer (score 1):

> When a value in the middle field textField is changed there are no
>   changes in resultDayField but only after pressing "Enter". I saw here
>   different solutions how to trace changes with DocumentListener and
>   JFormattedField but my case requires universal listener for all
>   widgets in panel to trace changes simultaneously. I don't undestand
>   how to mix ActionListener and DocumentListener to work them both. What
>   should I do?

Start by creating a method that takes the values from the date picker and text field, generates the required result and updates the right field

Use a ActionListener (or other appropriate listener) on the date picker, have this listener call your "update" method

Use a DocumentListener on the text field, when any of its event notification methods are called, call your "update" method

> Also if the middle field textField is empty choosing any date will
>   crash the application with null-pointer exception. But I didn't
>   understand why the app can't just write "Null".

`int days = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());` will cause an `Exception` when the text field is empty, because `""` is not a valid number, you need to check if the field has a value first before you do any additional calculations.

As to your last question, no, it's not unusual to use a single listener this way. While I've suggested using two different listeners in your case, they delegate their actual functionality to a shared method